# How to POST to an XML API?

Tags: php, api

We are integrating the [travel API of www.transhotel-dev.com](https://webservices.transhotel.com/usersite_web/index.jsp).

The code is like this:

```
<?php
$servletHOST = "www.transhotel-dev.com";
$servletPATH = "/interfaces/SController";
$pXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><Login><Username>Username</Username><Password>Password</Password></Login>";
$pCall = "Login";
$postdata = "pXML=" . urlencode($pXML) . "&pCall=" . urlencode($pCall);

$fp = pfsockopen($servletHOST, 1184);

if ($fp) {
    fputs($fp, "POST $servletPATH HTTP/1.0\n");
    fputs($fp, "Accept: */*\n");

    $strlength = strlen( $postdata );

    fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . $strlength . "\n\n");
    fputs($fp, $postdata . "\n" );

    $output = "";
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $output .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

HTTP compression and POST method are required to go beyond this point. Can anybody help?

Comment: I'd use cURL for this - doing it at a low level will be a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

The following calls require the use of https secure protocol
(https://www.transhotel-dev.com:1449/interfaces/SController):

- Login
- AddAmountCardHPlus
- GetNifInvoices
- NifAgencyReservations
- NifHotelReservations
- ConfirmReservation (When contain the data of a credit card)
- BuildSearchForm
- LoginRQ
- LoginB2B
- CreateAgency
- NifActivitiesReservations
- GetActivitiesProvider
- NifTransfersReservations
- GetTransfersProvider
- LoginHPlus
- UserLogInHPlus

so you should use ssl protocol for login action:

```
$fp = pfsockopen("ssl://www.transhotel-dev.com", 1449);
```